# Unique row no matter the column

Tags: sql, mysql, create-table, unique-constraint

Is there a way to make an entire row unique no matter what value the column is in?

So, if `1` is in col `a`, and `2` is in col `b`, then if you were to insert `2` into col `a` and `1` into col `b` an error would be thrown.

```
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | <- Would throw error on insert since this already exists above
+---+---+
```

Comment: Only by writing code to do the insert and check the conditions. However, if the number of columns and/or the number of rows then the code-based insert will be very slow compared to a normal SQL insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define 2 virtual generated columns with the least and the greatest of the 2 values and set a unique constraint on them:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  a INT NOT NULL, 
  b INT NOT NULL,
  x INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (LEAST(a, b)),
  y INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (GREATEST(a, b)),
  UNIQUE (x, y)
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FhwgTr8u).

Or, for MySql 8.0+:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  a INT NOT NULL, 
  b INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE ((LEAST(a, b)), (GREATEST(a, b))) -- don't miss the parentheses 
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TxWoYCZB).

Comment: Yes, and with MySQL 8.0, you can skip the generated columns. Just make the UNIQUE KEY on two expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You could enforce it with a trigger. But I can't think of a good way to do this with a UNIQUE KEY constraint.

It would be easier if you change the way you store values, so they are in a single column, on multiple rows of an additional table. Then you could easy use UNIQUE KEY to enforce uniqueness.

---

If you're trying to represent related items:

```
CREATE TABLE item_group (
  group_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE item_group_members (
  group_id INT NOT NULL,
  member_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (group_id, member_id)
);

INSERT INTO item_group_members VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2);
```

If you need each member to appear in only one group:

```
ALTER TABLE item_group_members ADD UNIQUE KEY (member_id);
```

Comment: How would a single column work? I am trying to build a table where `item a` complements `item b` so that they related to one another (similar to a friends list on a social network).

Answer (score 2):

Have third column `hash VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE`, where you would place sorted hash.
Sort it to always get same hash for values, no matter of their order: `1, 2, 2, 3` will have same hash as `3, 2, 1, 2`

E.g. in PHP:

```
sort($columns);
$hash = md5(implode('|', $columns));

$columns['hash'] = $hash;

$sql = "INSERT INTO my_tbl VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($columns);
```

Comment: I could hash the values using `MD5()` in mysql and order them from smallest to largest so that way the order will always be the same.

Comment: I assume you would also define a unique key constraint for the hash column?

Answer (score 1):

When inserting data check for duplicates using before-insert trigger like so:

```
if (exists(
  select 1
  from t
  where (least(a, b), greatest(a, b)) = (least(new.a, new.b), greatest(new.a, new.b))
)) then
  signal sqlstate value '45000' set message_text = 'cannot insert duplicate pair';
end if;
```

A simpler solution is to add `CHECK` constraint along with `UNIQUE` on your table:

```
alter table t add constraint unique (a, b)
alter table t add constraint check (a < b)
```

Now, you must store data so that `a < b`. If you try to insert `2, 1` the check fails. If you insert `1, 2` the unique constraint fails.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ar-fMDSU)